# How to reduce space between Blog Description and menu in blogger?

Tags: html, css

I tried the following two methods. none worked.

1) To remove it permanently
If you want to remove this unwanted space permanently and maintain only a required space between your blog title and blog description, incorporate following steps and edit your blog

Login to your blog>Click on Template>Click on Edit HTML>Search (Ctrl+F): .Header h1 { and below it find the codes that resemble the given code:

```
.header-inner .Header .titlewrapper {
padding: 22px $(header.padding);
}
```

To reduce the space between the blog title and blog description or tagline whatever you wants to call it, reduce padding px in above code. You are advised to start from -1. In my case, I will reduce from 22px to -22px. This gave only desired space between my blog title and blog description statement.

2) The following ALTERNATIVE also did not produce and results

Login to your blog>Click on Template>Click on Customize>Click on Advanced>Scroll down and click Add CSS>In Add Custom CSS area, copy and paste the given CSS:

```
.Header h1 {margin-bottom:0}
.Header .description {margin-top: 0;}
.header-inner .Header .titlewrapper {padding-bottom:0;}
```

Comment: Try adding `!important` just to be sure it is not working. And use DevTools to check if your css is being overridden.

Comment: i added '!important' nothing happened.